# Why does iPhone layout look different in xCode and in simulator?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've been developing a modified version of an iPad application, and try though I might, I've been unable to resolve the following issue.

Inteface Builder:[image: App, as seen in Interface Builder]

I'm using a UITableView to display cells of information, however the cells have huge gaps between them in the iPad emulator.

Simulator:
[image: App, as seen in emulator]

If anyone has any ideas that I could try, I'd be happy to test out any different ideas to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to my controller, and the TableView function.

Some of my cells were throwing errors, and so caused the returned cell to show as the ugly black space shown above.